# How to use trace sources in application code?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have successfully configured logging in the `App.config` file of an application. The relevant parts are as follows.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net.Http">
      <listeners>
        <add name="PushTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
  </switches>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="PushTraceListener"
         type="PushCore.Logging.LoggingTraceListener, PushCore" />
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                    logMalformedMessages="false"
                    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                    maxMessagesToLog="3000"
                    maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

While this works fine, I seem unable to do the same in the application code, which I tried as follows.

```
var LoggingTraceListener = new LoggingTraceListener
{ Name = "PushTraceListener", Filter = new LoggingTraceFilter() };
Trace.AutoFlush = true;                      
var TraceSourceNames = new string[] { "System.Net.Http" };

foreach (var TraceSourceName in TraceSourceNames)
{
    var TraceSource = new TraceSource(TraceSourceName, SourceLevels.Verbose);
    TraceSource.Switch = new SourceSwitch(TraceSourceName, "Verbose");
    TraceSource.Listeners.Add(LoggingTraceListener);
}

Trace.Listeners.Add(LoggingTraceListener);
```

The `TraceListener` itself seems to behave as expected, as it recieves messages written via `Trace`, but apparently not from the instantiated `TraceSource` instance. I somehow believe that instantiation of the `TraceSource` is not desired here, but instead an existing trace source would have to be used. However, I don't know how to do that.

Is it possible to achieve loggig as desired in the first place? If so, how?

A justified question would be why I would like to do access in code instead of using `App.config` if the configuration works fine. The reason is that `App.config` can only be used for an actual application but not for a Windows service.

Any suggestions?